# Opencv knn findNearest() incorrectly classifying images

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, computer-vision, knn

I am using Opencvs ml::KNearest class to classify images based on their nearest neighbor classifier and the algorithm/ program works for only the first image in the vector of images. Why might this be?

in previous lines of the code i populate the data and labels vectors.

```
vector<Mat> data;
vector<int> labels;

    Ptr<ml::KNearest> knn = ml::KNearest::create();
    knn->train(samples, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labels);
    cout << data.size() << endl;

    for (int iterate = 0; iterate < data.size(); iterate++) {
        Mat img = data.at(iterate);
        Mat sample;
        img.reshape(1, 1).convertTo(sample, CV_32F);
        float response = knn->predict(sample);

        cout << "Class label: " << response << endl;
    }
```

when the code reaches line

```
float response = knn->predict(sample);
```

I get an Unhandled exception "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFADDA5FDEC" Which i believe indicates that there is not an image being read. To ensure that the data vector was in fact populated i wrote a loop with an imshow statement to make sure the images were all there - and they are.

I attempted to take these statements out of the loop and just declare the Mat img one at at time but this resulted in the same exception.

EDIT:
thanks to @stateMachine I am now using findNearest() instead of predit which now looks like:

```
    Ptr<KNearest> knn = KNearest::create();
    knn->setAlgorithmType(KNearest::Types::BRUTE_FORCE);
    knn->train(samples, ROW_SAMPLE, labels);

    // Classify new image from directory 2
    vector<float> predictions;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Mat img = data.at(i);
        Mat sample;
        img.reshape(1, 1).convertTo(sample, CV_32F);
        float response = knn->findNearest(sample, knn->getDefaultK(), noArray());
        predictions.push_back(response);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < predictions.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Image " << i << " Class label: " << predictions.at(i) << endl;
    }
```

and I am stuck on the same issue - each image is read as class 0

this is where i declare the labels or classes

```
vector<Mat> data;
    vector<Mat> pushingAllImages;
    vector<int> labels;
    std::string path1bruh = "mydirectory";
    std::string path2bruh = "mydirectory";
    std::string path3bruh = "mydirectory";
    Mat img;
    Mat bruh;
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path1bruh)) {
        std::string name = entry.path().string();
        img = imread(name, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        //resize(img, bruh, Size(height2, width2));
        pushingAllImages.push_back(img);
        labels.push_back(0);
    }
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path2bruh)) {
        std::string name = entry.path().string();
        img = imread(name, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        //resize(img, bruh, Size(height2, width2));
        pushingAllImages.push_back(img);
        labels.push_back(1);
    }
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path3bruh)) {
        std::string name = entry.path().string();
        img = imread(name, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        //resize(img, bruh, Size(height2, width2));
        pushingAllImages.push_back(img);
        labels.push_back(2);
    }
```

am I incorrectly using findNearest?

Comment: Assuming the code until that point is working and not introducing other bugs... Are the sample dimensions the same you used for training the classifier? I'd suggest to inspect the `sample` mat before the call to `predict`. Make sure it has the same dimensions and type of the training data. It must match one row of the `samples` matrix.

Comment: Also... without *any* example of what your images look like, I can only guess... but are you sure that's the reshape you want? And... why aren't you using `cv::cvtColor()` to change the color space of your image?

Comment: Hold it! You are using a KNN classifier. With this classifier, you get the predictions via the [findNearest()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/dd/de1/classcv_1_1ml_1_1KNearest.html#a312f975c24725b57200e221a97474b45) method, not `predict`. You need to specify the number of nearest neighbors as well.

Comment: "Unhandled exception" means you must catch the exception and inspect it.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem, but you are not setting the number of nearest neighbors anywhere in your code. Please refer to the documentation for proper usage of the `findNearest()` function: https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/dd/de1/classcv_1_1ml_1_1KNearest.html#a312f975c24725b57200e221a97474b45

Comment: I'm guessing `knn->getDefaultK()` returns 1, which would be a sensible default.... unless it's not being sensible. yeah, best check that or straight up replace it with your own fixed value that makes sense for your situation.